# Returning to SWTOR after a couple of years - Level 55 class quests?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I've just decided to see what's what. Last time I played was in February 2014, so yea... obviously a lot has changed ;-)

Now that's fine. But I'm not sure where to go from here. Some of my characters are level 55, the rest 50. I don't seem to have any class quest available, but the game allows me to start a fresh character as level 60 to get right into the new content - Rise of the Hutt Cartel I believe. I don't want to do that however.

What would be the "expected" or "normal" progression from here?  Apologies if I'm missing something obvious; but the game can seem just a tad overwhelming when returning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After level 50 there are no more class quests (apart from one very small one on Rishi around level 58).

Level 50-55 is Rise of the Hutt Cartel, as you've noticed, and presumably already done on your level 55 characters.  It has one story per faction.

The next story expansion was Shadow of Revan from 55-60, which you can begin from a terminal your ship, and is partly faction-based but mostly a unified story.

After that are Knights of the Fallen Empire (60-65) and Knights of the Eternal Throne (65-70), which are entirely a unified story.

Comment: It's all coming back to me now hehe. Shadow of Revan was what threw me off, as it was listed as a Flashpoint and those are normally group missions. I'm back on track now, thank you :-)

Comment: @MarkCassidy the Shadow of Revan flashpoints (and a bunch of others) can be passed solo, the game provides you with a NPC droid assistant which is pretty powerful and infinite - if the one you already have is defeated, you can call on a new one via icon near the task.

Comment: @MarkCassidy [here is the list of flashpoints](https://www.swtorista.com/flashpoints), it contains all of them (at least Pre-Iokath ones) and information about which one can be solo-ed (see the `Story Mode` column).